# CefSharp build error with Azure pipeline :Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll'

Tags: azure-pipelines, cefsharp

I've added CefSharp(version 84.4.10.0) for windows forms. It is working on my machine and on my virtual machine without any problems.

As I found on Github I've added true to my project and set Prefare 32-bit to true. But when I'm trying to build it with Azure Pipeline-s I get error:

```
##[error]SGEN(0,0): Error : Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=SGEN;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=;]Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
SGEN : error : Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. [D:\a\1\s\SBS_BSales.csproj]
```

Here is my pipeline YEMEL

```
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.4.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.4.0
```

```
steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
```

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    createLogFile: true
```

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2223 if your not using sgen then simply disabling it should solve the problem.

Comment: How did you add the `CefSharp(version 84.4.10.0) `, by nuget package? If yes, would please share the log for the nuget restore task?  And the value of the `configuration` and `platform` of VS build task. After installing the nuget package, the project file will be modified. Have the project files in your repo been modified after installing the Nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iv Disabled SGEN XML generation from
project proports -> Selected Configuration Release -> Build->  Output-> Generate serialization assembly = No

and problem was solved :)